# How to optimize printing Pascal's Triangle in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, optimization, pascals-triangle

I have implemented the [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) in Python, it is pretty efficient, but it isn't efficient enough and there are a few things I don't like.

The Pascal's triangle is like the following:

[image]

I have read [this useless tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-print-pascals-triangle/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093387/pascals-triangle-for-python), and the solutions are extremely inefficient, involving factorials and don't use caching.

Instead, I implemented a different algorithm I created myself. My mathematics isn't that good, but I have spotted the following simple recursive relationships:

The triangle starts with a row with only 1 number in it, and that number is 1.

For each subsequent row, the length of the row increment by 1, and the first and last number of the row is 1.

Each number that isn't the first or last, is the sum of the number at the row above it with index equal to the number's index minus 1, and the number at row above it with the same index.

And the rows of the triangle are symmetric.

In other words, if we use zero-based indexing:

```
p(r, 0) = p(r, r) = 1
p(r, c) = p(r - 1, c - 1) + p(r - 1, c)
p(r, c) = p(r, r - c)
```

Below is my code:

```py
from typing import List

class Pascal_Triangle:
    def __init__(self, rows: int = 0, fill: bool = True):
        self.data = []
        self.length = 0
        if rows:
            self.fill_rows(rows)
        if fill:
            self.fill_values()

    def add_row(self, length: int):
        row = [0] * length
        row[0] = row[-1] = 1
        self.data.append(row)

    def fill_rows(self, rows: int):
        for length in range(self.length + 1, rows + 1):
            self.add_row(length)
        self.length = rows

    def comb(self, a: int, b: int) -> int:
        if not 0 <= b <= a:
            raise ValueError(f'cannot choose {b} elements from a population of {a}')

        if self.length < (length := a + 1):
            self.fill_rows(length)

        return self.at(a, b)

    def at(self, row: int, col: int) -> int:
        if val := self.data[row][row - col]:
            self.data[row][col] = val
            return val

        if val := self.data[row][col]:
            return val

        self.data[row][col] = val = self.at(row - 1, col - 1) + self.at(row - 1, col)
        return val

    def fill_values(self):
        for row in range(2, self.length):
            for col in range(1, row):
                self.at(row, col)

    def get_row(self, row: int) -> List[int]:
        if self.length < (length := row + 1):
            self.fill_rows(length)

        self.fill_values()
        return self.data[row]

    def pretty_print(self):
        print('\n'.join(f"{' ' * (self.length - i)}{' '.join(map(str, row))}" for i, row in enumerate(self.data)))
```

First, the output of `tri = Pascal_Triangle(12); tri.pretty_print()` is extremely ugly:

```
            1
           1 1
          1 2 1
         1 3 3 1
        1 4 6 4 1
       1 5 10 10 5 1
      1 6 15 20 15 6 1
     1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
    1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1
   1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
  1 10 45 120 210 252 210 120 45 10 1
 1 11 55 165 330 462 462 330 165 55 11 1
```

How can I dynamically adjust the spacing between the elements so that the output looks more like an equilateral triangle?

Second I don't like the recursive function, is there any way that I can get rid of the recursive function and calculate the values using the recursive relationship by iteration, while remembering already computed numbers?

Third, is there a data structure more efficient than my nested lists for the same data? I have thought of `numpy.array` but arrays need each row to have the same length and arrays can't grow.

Finally can my algorithm be optimized further?

---

The data after calling `tri.at(16, 5)` is:

```
[[1],
 [1, 1],
 [1, 2, 1],
 [1, 3, 3, 1],
 [1, 4, 6, 4, 1],
 [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1],
 [1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1],
 [1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 0, 1],
 [1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 9, 36, 84, 126, 126, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 10, 45, 120, 210, 252, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 11, 55, 165, 330, 462, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 12, 66, 220, 495, 792, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 78, 286, 715, 1287, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 364, 1001, 2002, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1365, 3003, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4368, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

---

I know I am already doing [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), and that is not what I meant. I want to calculate the unfilled values without ever using a recursive function. Instead of using the recursive definition and going backwards, we can somehow use iteration, start from where the lowest value that was filled and needed for the query, and iterate through all needed numbers, make two copies of each number and go forwards, until the requested index was reached.

The needed numbers can be computed using indexing and mathematics.

In this way there is no recursive function call at all.

---

### ***Update***

I have rewrote my code to the following:

```
class Pascal_Triangle:
    def __init__(self, end_row: int = 2, opt: int = 0):
        self.data = [[1], [1, 1]]
        self.length = 2
        self.opt = [self.add_rows_o0, self.add_rows_o1]
        if end_row > 2:
            self.opt[opt](end_row)

    def add_rows_o0(self, end_row: int):
        last_row = self.data[-1]
        for _ in range(self.length, end_row):
            self.data.append(
                last_row := [1] + [a + b for a, b in zip(last_row, last_row[1:])] + [1]
            )

        self.length = end_row

    def add_rows_o1(self, end_row: int):
        last_row = self.data[-1]
        for n in range(self.length, end_row):
            mid = n // 2 + 1
            row = [0] * (n - 1)
            m = n - 2
            for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(last_row, last_row[1:mid])):
                row[i] = row[m - i] = a + b

            self.data.append(last_row := [1] + row + [1])
        self.length = end_row

    def pretty_print(self):
        longest = len(str(self.data[-1][self.length // 2]))
        line_length = (longest + 1) * self.length
        for row in self.data:
            print(" ".join(f"{n:{longest}}" for n in row).center(line_length))
```

I have used [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Python) to generate new rows and got rid of the expensive recursive function call. The code is much faster as a result.

However, I tried to exploit the symmetric nature of the rows and only calculate half of the row and mirror it to get the other half. In this way the number of calculations would be halved.

But it is actually slower:

```
In [257]: %timeit Pascal_Triangle(64, 1)
237 µs ± 7.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [258]: %timeit Pascal_Triangle(64, 0)
224 µs ± 9.75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [259]: Pascal_Triangle(64, 1).data == Pascal_Triangle(64, 0).data
Out[259]: True
```

Why is it slower? And how can I actually skip the unnecessary calculations and make it faster?

Comment: About your update: Not sure, but you only save a single addition per cell, and (without diving into details how exactly it works) the second variant looks much more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can improve the `pretty_print` by getting the length (as string) of the longest number and using that as the basis for all the numbers' width; also using `str.center` might be easier.

   ```
    def pretty_print(self):
        longest = max(len(str(n)) for row in self.data for n in row)
        line_length = (longest + 1) * self.length
        for row in self.data:
            print(' '.join(f'{n:{longest}}' for n in row).center(line_length))
   ```
2. With this check `if val := self.data[row][col]: return val`, you are already doing that, and each value is calculated exactly once. You could make it purely iterative in `fill_values` directly, and drop the `at` method entirely, though:

   ```
    def fill_values(self):
        for row in range(2, self.length):
            for col in range(1, row):
                self.data[row][col] = self.data[row - 1][col - 1] + self.data[row - 1][col]
   ```
3. I'd say a nested list-of-lists is a good choice here, and your algorithm (even before 2.) should already be as efficient as possible.

---

Having said that, I noticed you have a `comb` function, so maybe your goal is not really to print the triangle, but to calculate individual values. In this case, there are two possible ways to make you code faster (although I did not actually time it).

First, you could use a `dict` as data structure and then only calculate the values that are actually needed to find the value `at` a given `row` and `col`. In the worst case (centre of bottom row) that will be 50% of the entire triangle, and on average much less than that.

```
class Pascal_Triangle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {(0, 0): 1}
        
    def fill_rows(self, rows: int):
        # actually, just the last row would be enough here...
        for row in range(rows + 1):
            for col in range(row + 1):
                self.at(row, col)
        
    def at(self, row: int, col: int) -> int:
        if not 0 <= col <= row:
            raise ValueError(f'column position {col} is invalid for row {row}')
        if (row, col) not in self.data:
            self.data[row, col] = 1 if col in (0, row) else self.at(row - 1, col - 1) + self.at(row - 1, col)
        return self.data[row, col]
    
    def pretty_print(self):
        longest = max(len(str(n)) for n in self.data.values())
        max_row = max(row for (row, col) in self.data)
        line_length = (longest + 1) * max_row
        for row in range(max_row+1):
            print(' '.join(str(self.data.get((row,col), "")).center(longest) for col in range(row + 1)).center(line_length))
```

This version still has the `fill_rows` and `pretty_print` functions (nicely showing which values were actually calculated). If you don't need those, you could also just make `at` a function and use `functools.cache` to cache the values...

```
from functools import cache

@cache
def at(row: int, col: int) -> int:
    if not 0 <= col <= row:
        raise ValueError(f'column position {col} is invalid for row {row}')
    return 1 if col in (0, row) else at(row - 1, col - 1) + at(row - 1, col)
```

... or calculate the binomial coefficient directly using factorials:

```
    from math import factorial as fac
    def comb(n, k):
        return fac(n) // (fac(k)*(fac(n-k)))
```

Comment: After comparing, your pretty_print is indeed far prettier than mine ;)

Comment: The longest is the middle (or max) value in the last row, no need to search everywhere. Btw, every alive Python version (i.e., 3.8 and newer) has `math.comb`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to simplify the creation of rows, and to make (arguably) better the pretty-printing:

```
class Pascal_Triangle:
    def __init__(self, end_row: int = 1):
        self.rows = [[1], [1, 1]]
        if end_row > 1:
            self.add_rows(end_row)
    
    def add_rows(self, end_row: int):
        last_row = self.rows[-1]
        for i in range(len(self.rows), end_row + 1):
            last_row = [1] + [last_row[i] + last_row[i+1] for i in range(len(last_row) - 1)]  + [1]
            self.rows.append(last_row)
    
    def pretty_print(self):
        width = len(str(self.rows[-1][len(self.rows)//2]))
        print('\n'.join(f"{' ' * width * (len(self.rows) - i)}{(' '*width).join(map(lambda n:f'{n:{width}}', row))}" for i, row in enumerate(self.rows)))

tri = Pascal_Triangle(6)
tri.pretty_print()

#               1
#             1   1
#           1   2   1
#         1   3   3   1
#       1   4   6   4   1
#     1   5  10  10   5   1
#   1   6  15  20  15   6   1

tri.add_rows(9)
tri.pretty_print()

#                                1
#                             1     1
#                          1     2     1
#                       1     3     3     1
#                    1     4     6     4     1
#                 1     5    10    10     5     1
#              1     6    15    20    15     6     1
#           1     7    21    35    35    21     7     1
#        1     8    28    56    70    56    28     8     1
#     1     9    36    84   126   126    84    36     9     1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to obtain a Pascal's triangle line without recursion:

```
def pascalLine(N):
    r = [1]
    for p in range(N):
        r.append(r[-1]*(N-p)//(p+1))
    return r
```

To format the output nicely, you can compute the size of the largest number and use that to print numbers with a fixed width (which makes the alignment much easier to compute):

```
N     = 10
width = len(str(max(pascalLine(N-1))))*2
for i in range(N):
    line = "".join(f"{n:^{width}}" for n in pascalLine(i)).center(width*N)
    print(line)
```

#### Output

```
                             1
                          1     1
                       1     2     1
                    1     3     3     1
                 1     4     6     4     1
              1     5     10    10    5     1
           1     6     15    20    15    6     1
        1     7     21    35    35    21    7     1
     1     8     28    56    70    56    28    8     1
  1     9     36    84   126   126    84    36    9     1
```

You could also compute the Pascal lines as you go, but you need to estimate the size of the largest value in order to get proper formatting.  For a Pascal's triangle, the sum of numbers on each line is 2^N, so the maximum value of a line will be at most half of that.

```
# Pascal's triangle size
N = 10

# Estimate fixed value printing width
width  = len(str(2**(N-1))) + 2 # extra for spacing

# Print each line centred, with centred numbers
P = [1]
for i in range(N):
    print("".join(str(n).center(width) for n in P).center(width*N))
    P = [1,*map(sum,zip(P,P[1:])),1] # Compute next line
```

#### Output

```
                             1
                          1     1
                       1     2     1
                    1     3     3     1
                 1     4     6     4     1
              1     5     10    10    5     1
           1     6     15    20    15    6     1
        1     7     21    35    35    21    7     1
     1     8     28    56    70    56    28    8     1
  1     9     36    84   126   126    84    36    9     1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit refinement of [the above answer of Alain T.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76755745/10503796) counting the symmetry of Pascal coefficients.
Moreover, we can avoid division inside the `for` loop with replacing

```
r.append(r[-1]*(n-k)//(k+1))
```

by calling recusively

```
r.append(pascalLine(n-1)[k]+pascalLine(n-1)[k+1])
```

Full Python code:

```
def pascalLine(n):
    r = [1]
    for k in range(n//2): 
        #r.append(r[-1]*(n-k)//(k+1))
        r.append(pascalLine(n-1)[k]+pascalLine(n-1)[k+1])
    if n%2==0: r=r+r[-2::-1]
    else: r=r+r[-1::-1]
    return r

n=9
# Print out as isoceles triangle
a=pascalLine(n-1)
MAX_LENGTH=len("   ".join(str(a[i]) for i in range(len(a))))

for i in range(n):
    a=pascalLine(i)
    s="   ".join(str(a[i]) for i in range(len(a)))
    print(s.center(MAX_LENGTH))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that I have modified the code to completely eliminate duplicate calculations.

I observed that, if the tip of Pascal's triangle has a row index of 0, then all numbers in odd indexed rows appear exactly twice, and all numbers except the middle number appears twice.

And of course Pascal's triangle is symmetric. So we can just compute exactly half of the row and flip it to complete the row.

Since the midpoint doesn't duplicate in even indexed rows, we need to exclude the last item in the half row when reversing it.

Full code:

```
class Pascal_Triangle:
    def __init__(self, end_row: int = 3):
        self.data = [[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1]]
        self.length = 3
        if end_row > 3:
            self.add_rows(end_row)

    def add_rows(self, end_row: int):
        last_row = self.data[-1]
        for n in range(self.length, end_row):
            mid = n // 2 + 1
            row = [a + b for a, b in zip(last_row, last_row[1:mid])]
            self.data.append(last_row := [1] + row + row[mid - 3 + n % 2 :: -1] + [1])

        self.length = end_row

    def pretty_print(self):
        longest = len(str(self.data[-1][self.length // 2]))
        line_length = (longest + 1) * self.length
        for row in self.data:
            print(" ".join(f"{n:^{longest}}" for n in row).center(line_length))
```

#### Output

```
In [2416]: p = Pascal_Triangle(18)

In [2417]: p.pretty_print()
                                                     1
                                                  1     1
                                               1     2     1
                                            1     3     3     1
                                         1     4     6     4     1
                                      1     5    10    10     5     1
                                   1     6    15    20    15     6     1
                                1     7    21    35    35    21     7     1
                             1     8    28    56    70    56    28     8     1
                          1     9    36    84    126   126   84    36     9     1
                       1    10    45    120   210   252   210   120   45    10     1
                    1    11    55    165   330   462   462   330   165   55    11     1
                 1    12    66    220   495   792   924   792   495   220   66    12     1
              1    13    78    286   715  1287  1716  1716  1287   715   286   78    13     1
           1    14    91    364  1001  2002  3003  3432  3003  2002  1001   364   91    14     1
        1    15    105   455  1365  3003  5005  6435  6435  5005  3003  1365   455   105   15     1
     1    16    120   560  1820  4368  8008  11440 12870 11440 8008  4368  1820   560   120   16     1
  1    17    136   680  2380  6188  12376 19448 24310 24310 19448 12376 6188  2380   680   136   17     1

In [2418]: %timeit Pascal_Triangle(18)
23 µs ± 627 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```